# Optimizing rarely used server installed in an always up virtual machine

Tags: virtualbox, optimization, headless

I have a Ubuntu Server installation on VirtualBox since I am a Mac OS X user and I want to launch some Linux-dependent programs on Ubuntu rarely by connecting it via SSH. Therefore I want to make a fine tuning to Ubuntu installation (not as much as changing the kernel) to consume less system resources.

On the idle state (no ssh clients connected, no intentional user programs running) it consumes about %2-2.5 CPU and 450 MB of RAM.

I'm looking for ways to decrease this. Main purpose is to develop some C programs using vim and gcc.

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas (maybe a bit obvious):

- Use 32-bit if at all possible, 64-bit uses more RAM
- Stick to CLI environment (do an expert install from alternate ISO)
- Suspend it when not in use! This is the best way to conserve RAM and it only takes 5-10 seconds to bring it back up.

Answer (score 1):

Look at services you don't use, and remove them. CUPS comes up to my mind. Desktop helpers like wheather-plugin and so on.

Comment: there's no desktop environment. this is ubuntu server. how can I see running services?

Comment: `runlevel` to detect the current runlevel. `ls /etc/rc2.d/` if the runlevel is 2, for example. `ps` shows the running processes. In most cases, daemons will end in a `d` like `cupsd, sshd` but not always, and not all processes ending in d are daemons.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the demands of your applications the [Ubuntu Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) requires a minimum of 128 MB RAM. So this is the minimum of RAM you should give to your virtual machine. Further steps to reduce resource usage may be:

- After having launched a virtual machine terminate Virtual Box Manager to free system resources.
- To further reduce RAM usage there also is a possibility to run Virtual Box in [headless mode](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vboxheadless) by issuing:

  ```
  VBoxManage startvm "VM name" --type headless
  ```

  By this you will only have access to your virtual machine over a RDP protocol (PUEL-Version of Virtual Box required!). The Virtual Box Manager and GUI elements will not be launched.
- Of course you could also purge all unwanted applications from your Ubuntu Server installation but this will only free some hard disk space (which should not be a relevant issue nowadays).
- As has [aready be mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52737/optimizing-rarely-used-ubuntu-for-always-up-virtual-machine/52743#52743) some unwanted services may be removed but this could affect system stability.

If you need a very lean Linux system you may consider to go the other way by choosing a distribution that installs only a basic OS where you need to add (rather than remove) all applications needed.